# Escaping quotes in mysql query string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to query my mysql database in Node for a complete table. The name of the table is supplied via a string from javascript. 
Mysql throws an error because if I insert it into the query in the following way it results in this error:

> `'{"code":"ER_PARSE_ERROR","errno":1064,"sqlMessage":"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1$2_Anzahl_der_Anrufe'' at line 1","sqlState":"42000","index":0,"sql":"SELECT * FROM '1$2_Anzahl_der_Anrufe'"}'`

```
    let result = [];
    tableName = '1$2_Anzahl_der_Anrufe'

    connectionData.query('SELECT * FROM ?', [tableName], function (err, res) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        if (res.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                result.push(res[i]);
            }
        }
        callback(result);
    });
```

If I try it directly in mysql without the quotes everything works or if insert it directly without the question mark in my js code. How can I escape the quotes?

Comment: If you allow the user to specify the table name, that's as good as any other SQL injection. `SELECT * FROM admin_users`. Why, thanks.

Comment: The user selects the name indirectly from a dropdown menu and isn't able to change it.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM 1$2_Anzahl_der_Anrufe` isn't a valid query when I run it. Regardless, this isn't about the quotes. Your code inserts `1$2_Anzahl_der_Anrufe`, not `'1$2_Anzahl_der_Anrufe'`.

Comment: As for the injection issue, you can change client side code easily. Anything a user sends has to be validated and sanitized on the server, always. And anybody can write, say, a Python script that pretends to be a browser and sends arbitrary requests to your server.

Comment: *"from a dropdown menu and isn't able to change it"* – *laughs in HTTP* – If you believe a client-side dropdown menu will prevent users from submitting arbitrary values via HTTP, you know nothing Jon Snow.

Comment: After it is sent to the server, it is checked against an existing list of names. Is that fine?

Comment: Yes, that'd be fine. And if you do that, you don't need to parameterise the value and can simply concatenate it into the string.